# LSTM output dimensionality

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras

I am new to LSTMs. When reading the papers and websites about LSTM architecture, there is something I do not get.

As I understand it, a single LSTM layer can have multiple LSTM cells (just like a regular dense layer). However, what would the shape the output of that layer look like? Lets assume we are not returning sequences and only returning the final timestep value. With a single LSTM cell, the output of each cell is a vector, as opposed to a single Dense layer cell, where the output of each cell is a scalar number. With multiple LSTM cells in one layer, what would you do to the vectors to turn N vectors (with N LSTM cells in that layer) into a single vector to push into the next layer? Thank you, and sorry for my inexperience.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've confused the dimensionality of an LSTM (the number of "units" it has and the sequence length.

> As I understand it, a single LSTM layer can have multiple LSTM cells
>   (just like a regular dense layer)

An LSTM "cell" is just what library implementors use to describe an object which computes the LSTM update for a single time-step. As such, a regular dense layer has no such concept of "cell".

> However, what would the shape the output of that layer look like?

Usually something like (batch size, sequence length, dims) if you want a sequence, and you can manually index the sequence length dimension to extract the last output.

> So the "cell" count is equal to the time step count that it is on,
>   while the unit count is the amount of LSTMs per layer?

No, not quite. There is just one cell, which is invoked $T$ times to process a sequence of length $T$.

> The output of an LSTM unit is a vector, which can easily be taken as
>   an input into a following dense layer. However, if our LSTM layer
>   consists of N LSTM units, each producing a vector as output, assuming
>   we are not returning sequences but just the final time step output,
>   how do we combine those N output vectors into just one vector to push
>   into the following dense layer? Thank you.

An LSTM almost always has $N > 1$ units. An LSTM with one unit would have a scalar output. It's usually more helpful to think of an LSTM as having a state of a certain dimension $d$, rather than to think of it as having $d$ "units" inside.

Comment: So the "cell" count is equal to the time step count that it is on, while the unit count is the amount of LSTMs per layer? I have one more question. The output of an LSTM unit is a vector, which can easily be taken as an input into a following dense layer. However, if our LSTM layer consists of N LSTM units, each producing a vector as output, assuming we are not returning sequences but just the final time step output, how do we combine those N output vectors into just one vector to push into the following dense layer? Thank you.

Comment: @tomriddle I've edited my answer to answer your comment

Comment: This helps me a lot. However, I still have some points that I am unclear about. Is an LSTM "unit" an entire LSTM layer or a single LSTM "piece" analogous to how a  "piece" of a dense layer is a single neuron? So if the dimensionality of a Dense layer is D because it has D neurons in it, the dimensionality of an LSTM layer with D pieces would also be D? Thanks

Comment: @tomriddle yes, an LSTM "unit" is just a piece of the layer.

Comment: Sorry if this is getting repetitive or annoying for you, and thanks for answering my questions. So if you can have multiple LSTM units per layer, and each unit outputs a vector (assuming we are not returning sequences and only the last output is being emitted), how do we combine the vector outputs of every unit within a layer to produce one vector to push into a following dense layer?

Comment: @tomriddle "units" themselves don't output anything. The LSTM outputs the hidden state at each time step. The hidden state is a vector of numbers, and some people like to call each scalar component of this vector a "unit".

Comment: Looking at the formula for LSTM output, I see that the hidden state at each time step is the elementwise product of two vectors (which would result in a vector). This is the part that confuses me. If each "piece" of the LSTM layer outputs a vector as its hidden state at some time step, and each LSTM layer consists of several "pieces", how do we combine the vector output from each "piece" of the LSTM layer into one vector to push into a following dense layer? Thanks

Comment: @tomriddle try not to think in terms of pieces or units at all -- I think it just causes confusion.

Comment: Okay, so let me start from the bottom about how I think it works, and then it will be easy to point out where I am wrong. A single LSTM layer consists of D LSTM cells, analogous to a D dimensional dense layer. Each cell takes in an input vector concatenated to the previous hidden state of the same cell, and outputs a new hidden state, and updates the current cell state. Since there are D LSTM cells in this layer, that means there are D outputs for this layer, where each output is a vector. I am confused on how to turn those D vectors into one vector to treat as the layer output. (1/2)

Comment: Can you point out where my understanding of it is wrong? Thank you (2/2)

Comment: @tomriddle An LSTM layer does not consist of LSTM cells. A "cell" is a useful programming abstraction for implementation, but does not actually exist.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand now. So each layer composes of a single set of operations, where the operations are 1) Concatenating the input vector to the previous time step hidden state, 2) Calculating the gates (4 operations, activation input output forget), 3) Calculating the Cell State, 4) Using the Cell state and the output gate to calculate the Hidden State at that time step. Did I finally understand it right?

Comment: @tomriddle yes, that's right

Comment: Thank you for your help. One more thing, in the equations for the gates, we take the dot product of the weight vectors and the input vectors, before adding a bias. Would this not produce a scalar for the gates (taking the dot of two vectors) rather than a vector, like I would expect it should? Thanks.

Comment: @tomriddle which gate are you talking about? can you point to a reference?

Comment: [this](http://nicodjimenez.github.io/2014/08/08/lstm.html) is one reference, though I can give many others if required. The gates I am referencing are the activation, input, forget, and output gates, each of which, according to these online resources, computes a nonlinearity function applied to the dot of the corresponding weight and input vectors.

Comment: @tomriddle the product between a weight matrix and the input vector is a vector, not a scalar

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought the weight matrix was a one dimensional matrix, essentially a vector, since that is what they used at [this link](https://blog.aidangomez.ca/2016/04/17/Backpropogating-an-LSTM-A-Numerical-Example/). Thank you for the clarification you have provided me so far. I think I understand everything, and will update here if I have a misclarification. Thanks